# BigQuery RANK() in Having or Where Clause

Tags: java, sql, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

In BigQuery I have a query that uses the `RANK()` function to group users by total count across sources. I only care about the top 10 users. Currently, I am doing the `RANK()` function in a sub-select with the `WHERE` clause living in a parent query to limit the results. Could someone explain to me how I could accomplish this without the parent query? The query I'd like to run looks like this:

```
SELECT source, user, count( tweet_id ) as total, max( friends ) as friends, 
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY source ORDER BY total DESC, friends DESC ) as user_rank
FROM tweets
GROUP BY source, user
HAVING user_rank <= 10
```

But I get Error: Field 'user_rank' not found in table 'tweets'. I can `ORDER BY` using user_rank, just not filter.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to do something like

```
SELECT source, user, total, friends, user_rank

FROM (
    SELECT source, user, count( tweet_id ) as total, max( friends ) as friends, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY source ORDER BY total DESC, friends DESC ) as user_rank
    FROM tweets
    GROUP BY source, user
) 

HAVING user_rank <= 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, that's actually what I'm doing currently. The downside is that the sub-query returns ~500k rows and I'd like to see if there was a better way to do it. Trying to head off the GROUP EACH BY warnings.

Comment: Why is 500k rows a problem? Can you move the group by to the outer query and change the having to a where so it filters first?

Comment: Hey Jordan, I'm just trying to avoid the `GROUP EACH BY` statement. Everything is working currently, but I was under the impression that `GROUP EACH BY` was not the best?